# SQL Server change column format to rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

My DB records are in column format:

```
ingredient    product
Ing1            AAA
Ing1            BBB
Ing2            AAA
Ing2            BBB
...             ...
```

I would like see data in format:

```
product    ingredient1      ingredient2
AAA           Ing1              Ing2
BBB           Ing1              Ing2
```

```
select *
from
(
  select product, ingredient
  from db 
) as d
pivot
(
  max(ingredient)
  for ingredient in ( ingredient1 , ingredient2)
) piv
```

But this query return empty `ingredient1` and `ingredient2`.

Comment: There can be only `Ing1` and `Ing2` as ingridients? Or It can be `Ing3`? All of ingridients end with number? `Ing1 = ingridient1`, `Ing2 = ingridient2`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server dynamic PIVOT query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use this type of query:

```
SELECT
    product,
    MAX(CASE WHEN ingredient = 'Ing1' THEN ingredient END) AS ingredient1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN ingredient = 'Ing2' THEN ingredient END) AS ingredient2
FROM 
    db
GROUP BY
    product;
```

Comment: 'Ing1' and 'Ing2' can't be static values

Comment: @Klapsius And how you choose an `ingredient` to come below `ingredient1` or `ingredient2`?

Comment: I change ingredient=ingredient then returns save value into both culumns

Comment: @Klapsius You should be more specific on this ;).

Answer (score 0):

In `PIVOT IN([Ing1], [Ing2])` you should use original names of values, later you can alias them in following:

```
SELECT product, 
       [Ing1] as [Ingridient1], 
       [Ing2] as [Ingridient2]
FROM
(
  SELECT product, ingredient
  FROM #t1 
) AS d
PIVOT
(
  MAX(ingredient)
  FOR ingredient IN ([Ing1], [Ing2])
) piv
```

---

You can check working example at **<kbd>[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f5e44/2)</kbd>**

Comment: return Ingredient1 and Ingredient2 empty

Comment: Check sql fiddle, It's returning as expected, you do something wrong http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f5e44/2

Comment: Same returns empty values.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a dynamic pivot as:

```
declare @Finalcollist varchar(max), @collist varchar(max)
declare @sql nvarchar(max)

select @Finalcollist = COALESCE(@Finalcollist + ', ','') 
                      + QUOTENAME(ingredient) +' AS '
                      + Replace (QUOTENAME(ingredient),'Ing','Ingredient')
from 
( SELECT DISTINCT ingredient FROM test1) T (ingredient)


select @collist = COALESCE(@collist + ', ','') 
                      + QUOTENAME(ingredient)                     
from 
( SELECT DISTINCT ingredient FROM test1) T (ingredient)

select @Finalcollist,@collist -- This givesdynamic column list

-- Now setting this @Finalcollist variable in the Dynamic SQL.
set @sql = '
select product, ' + @Finalcollist + '
from 
(select product,ingredient from test1
 )p
PIVOT(MAX (ingredient) FOR ingredient IN ( ' + @collist + ' )
) AS pvt
ORDER BY product'

--print @sql

EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql
```

<kbd>[DEMO](http://rextester.com/UDBOL5369)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Here some fun tryout with which you can have as many Ing's and it will increase the number of columns.

```
CREATE TABLE #temp(ing nvarchar(5), pr nvarchar(5))
INSERT INTO #temp values ('Ing1','AA')
INSERT INTO #temp values ('Ing1','BB')
INSERT INTO #temp values ('Ing2','AA')
INSERT INTO #temp values ('Ing2','BB')
INSERT INTO #temp values ('Ing3','AA')

DECLARE @PivotCols VARCHAR(MAX);
SELECT @PivotCols = COALESCE(@PivotCols + ',','') + QUOTENAME(ing) FROM #temp GROUP BY ing ORDER BY ing
EXEC
(
'SELECT * FROM #temp PIVOT
(
    MAX(ing) FOR ing IN (' + @PivotCols + ')
) pvt
')

DROP TABLE #temp
```

This will result as;

```
pr    Ing1  Ing2  Ing3
----- ----- ----- -----
AA    Ing1  Ing2  Ing3
BB    Ing1  Ing2  NULL
```